# Passing params to methods in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I am confused with one trivial thing - passing parameters to the method and changing their values... I'll better give you some code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer val = new Integer(41);
    upd(val);
    System.out.println(val);

    Man man = new Man();
    updMan(man);
    System.out.println(man.name);
  }

  static void upd(Integer val) {
    val = new Integer(42);
  }

  static void updMan(Man man) {
    man.name = "Name";
  }

  static class Man {
    String name;
  }
}
```

Could you explain why the Integer object I've passed is not updated while the Man object is? Aren't the Integer and Man objects passed by reference (due to their non-primitive nature)?

Comment: Hope you are misunderstanding java's `pass by value` concept. Read on that, it would be interesting. Also I would suggest you to go through the immutability of wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely should do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for `Integer` your are creating a new Object. For `Man` you just change one of its value, the object `man` stays the same.

Consider the following:

```
static void updMan(Man man) {
  man = new Man();
  man.name = "Another Man";
}
```

This would also not change your initial `man`.

--EDIT

You can "simulate" the mutability of `Integer` by this:

```
static void upd(Integer val) {
    try {
        Field declaredField = val.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        declaredField.set(val, 42);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That means, if Integer class was mutable, I could set the new value to it and it would have changed? And in case of primitives, the result would be similar - I won't be able to change the param value?

Comment: @iozee: That's correct, see my edited answer of how to simulate the mutability of Integer.

Comment: Thank you! The example with reflection (I guess) is quite inspiring :)

Comment: Well, using reflection to bypass java's access mechanism is not really good style and should be used only if there's no better solution. This is especially true for immutable classe. Look at this: `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(3); upd(i); System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(3).`

Comment: @HeikoSchmitz: yes sure, that was just for clarify the circumstances. I think iozee understood it like this. But thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

It is called *Pass by value*. When you pass some object to dome method, Java creates a copy of reference to that object. If you check object's hashcode right after going into method's body it will be the same as passed object's one. But when you change it inside of method, object changes and reference is no longer points to same object.

**EDIT**: code sample

```
public class TestPass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ss= "sample";
        System.out.println("Outside method: "+ss.hashCode());
        method(ss);

    }

    static void method(String s){
        System.out.println("Inside method: "+s.hashCode());
        s+='!';
        System.out.println("Inside method after object change: "+s.hashCode());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Outside method: -909675094
Inside method: -909675094
Inside method after change: 1864843191
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. So in other words, the reference bocomes "method-local" when you change **it's** value?

Comment: Yes. In case of strings they are also immutable, so changed string like in sample in answer's EDIT, won't be same object anyway.

Answer (score 1):

objects as parameters in Java are transferred as a params by copy of reference - so if you change the object via reference copy - you will have your object updated.

in case of your `upd(Integer val)` method you create a new `Integer` object so that reference copy now point to a new object, not the old one. So changing that object will not affect the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
man.name = "Name";
```

You are actually changing something in the same object here and not creating a new object as you did in In case of Integer.